# How to call angular2 component method from outside and have reference to this?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to call a method from a angular2 service from outside and from that method to call other method from same class or to have access to variables inited in construct.

I am using ngZone to make a method accesible from outside. My class looks like this:

```
var Component1 = ng.core.Class({
  constructor:[ng.core.NgZone, function(_ngZone) {
                    window.Component = {
                        onCallFromOutside: this.onCallFromOutside,
                        zone: _ngZone
                    };
                    this.some_var = "AAA";

                }],

  onCallFromOutside: function(){
    console.log("Called onCallFromOutside")
    console.log(this.some_var) // This is null
    this.inisdeCall() // Here I get error: EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.inisdeCall is not a function
  }
  inisdeCall: function(){
    console.log("Called inisdeCall")
  }

})
```

And I call this method from outside like this:

```
window.Component.zone.run(function(){
    window.Component.onCallFromOutside(e);
})
```

And this is the error I get:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.inisdeCall is not a function
```

I am using angular2 in plain JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you reference a function so you lost the `this` instance.

You could use the `bind` method to bind your function to the `this` object:

```
var Component1 = ng.core.Class({
  constructor:[ng.core.NgZone, function(_ngZone) {
    window.Component = {
      onCallFromOutside: this.onCallFromOutside.bind(this), // <-------
      zone: _ngZone
    };
    this.some_var = "AAA";
  }],
  (...)
```